# Is "New begin" proper English?

Tags: word-choice, speech

This might be a pretty basic question.

I'm writing a song.
It's usually written as `New beginning`,
but I thought that I might have heard people saying `New begin`.
It would sound better in this case, but is it proper English?

Comment: It's your song, you can do whatever you like. Just make sure your poetic license isn't expired. That said, native speakers would not / do not say "new begin", though "fresh start" is fairly well established:

Comment: _Begin_ is listed as a noun in Wiktionary. But then most strings seem to be listed there as most parts of speech. They _do_ label it as 'nonstandard'. _Newbiggin_ is a town in Northumberland.

Comment: You could, if you're looking for a song title or catch phrase, use "begin anew" or even "begin again", or some such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"New begin" is not proper English.  *Begin* is a verb, *Beginning* is a noun.  To precede it with an adjective like *New*, you'd expect a noun.  You might have heard an English speaker saying it quickly, without enunciating clearly, and the "-ing" couldn't be heard well, sounding like "begin" by itself.

If you're trying to shorten the phrase for the purposes of your song, you might try "New start".  Of course, if you're trying to rhyme with *begin*, that doesn't work.